# PrimeNG Listbox - Select and immediately deselect an option?

Tags: angular, listbox, primeng, angular5

**Background:**
Hey there! I'm using Angular 5 and the most recent update of PrimeNG (5.2.0). I'm trying to use a PrimeNG Listbox such that when you select an option in the Listbox, the value of said item appears in a text box, and then that option deselects itself so that the user can select that same option again.

[Here's the stackblitz for what I currently have.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-26yj6a?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

As you can see, the first time you click on an option in the Listbox, it deselects itself successfully. However, any subsequent times you click on the Listbox, the option no longer deselects.

**Attempted solutions:** My current code, if you can't see the stackblitz, is as follows:

**html:**

```
<p-listbox [options]="cities"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
           [style]="{'width':'200px'}"
           optionLabel="name"
           filter="filter"
           (onChange)="addField()"></p-listbox>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text">
```

**app.component.ts:** (excluding the imports for space's sake)

```
  cities;

  selectedCity;

  text: string = '';

  constructor() {
    this.cities = [
      {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
      {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
      {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
      {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
      {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
    ];
  }

  addField() {
    this.text += this.selectedCity.code;
    this.selectedCity = null;
  }
```

On change of the Listbox's value, I concatenate the selected option's value to a string, which is bound to the text input field. Then I set the selected option variable (selectedCity) to be null, which in theory should 'clear' the selection. I'm not quite sure why it works the first time but stops working after that. I have a feeling it has to do with how onChange handles changes, but I'm not quite sure.

Thank you for any help and explanations!

**Update:** Looks like (onChange) is unfortunately not super reliable for detecting changes, so I've switched it to a (click) and it works now.